# Android Asynctask update query to remote mysql server

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I want to run a simple query from an `AsyncTask` in an app that tells a remote MYSQL database to set some values from 1 to 0.

It's a php script called `resetSentValues.php` and when I access the file in my browser, the values in the database change. So I could say the script works.

What I would like is that, I could click a button and all values in my database are reset (with the working script). I tried with a simple `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
public class MessageSentResetter extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    private URL urlMsgtSateResetScript;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnectionMsgStateReset = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            urlMsgtSateResetScript = new URL("http://freerunnl.nl/smsSender/webservice/resetSentValues.php");
            System.out.println("message sent resetter on pre execute tried");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            urlConnectionMsgStateReset = (HttpURLConnection) urlMsgtSateResetScript.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        System.out.println("Onpostexecute is reached, now disconnect the httpurlconnection");
        urlConnectionMsgStateReset.disconnect();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

And I called it like this:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void sendSMS() {
    MessageSentResetter resetter = new MessageSentResetter();
    resetter.execute();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The message sent values are reset", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Where the click event is instantiated like so:

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sendSMS();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? I have it set up similarly already so that I can select and parse JSON objects from my database so the connection works. But I just want to execute this script with a simple button click now.

Thanks a lot for taking your time!

Comment: You're just opening a connection, but not making any get or post request to the url.

Comment: i only want to run the php file, i think i forgot to call 'urlConnectionMsgStateReset.connect();' ? i'm going to try this out now.

Comment: and i did urlConnectionMsgStateReset.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: Only `connect` should not going to work. Server side APIs should be POST, GET, PUT or DELETE requests. You need to see how to make a GET/POST request using Volley.

Comment: fun thing is, i had this working earlier today and then i tried to clean some of the code up and i found that it didnt work anymore. So now im checking everything again, and i have another function like this one that was working earlier as well but now just works partly. So i want to make this reset function from bottom up maybe stack overflow could help spot the mistakes

Comment: oh it works now

Comment: Glad to know that.

Comment: yeah im sorry, later tonight i'll correct the thread

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MessageSentResetter extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
private URL urlMsgtSateResetScript;
//HttpURLConnection urlConnectionMsgStateReset = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnectionMsgStateReset;


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();



}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try {
        urlMsgtSateResetScript = new URL("http://freerunnl.nl/smsSender/webservice/resetValues.php");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "exception";
    }


    try {
        urlConnectionMsgStateReset = (HttpURLConnection) urlMsgtSateResetScript.openConnection();
        urlConnectionMsgStateReset.setReadTimeout(15000);
        urlConnectionMsgStateReset.setRequestMethod("POST");

        urlConnectionMsgStateReset.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnectionMsgStateReset.setDoOutput(true);



        urlConnectionMsgStateReset.connect();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        int response_code = urlConnectionMsgStateReset.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("The response code for the resetter is");
        System.out.println(response_code);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    System.out.println("Onpostexecute is reached, now disconnect the httpurlconnection");
    urlConnectionMsgStateReset.disconnect();
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

it works now, when i click a button, the php script on my server is ran.